# Выдает ошибку "Different number of lines: out = 3, corr = 0" Не понимаю в чем проблема

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from datetime import datetime
import math
import time


def time_decorator(func):
  def wrapper():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    res_1 = func()
    finish_time = (datetime.now() - start_time).seconds
    print(round(finish_time))
    return res_1
  return wrapper
@time_decorator
def sleep_1_sec():
 time.sleep(1)
 print("function")
 return 25

result = sleep_1_sec()

print(result)
```

ниже я скинул условие которое они хотят
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PWCZ.png

Comment: кто где это выдает - ваш код работает без ошибок

Comment: прохожц курс в яндекс контесте , вбиваю туда код  и мне почему-то выдает эту ошибку , сам не понимаю почему и как

Comment: а что они просят вывести?

Comment: я сделал правку , скинул скрин условия , думаю теперь будет понятно чего они хотят

Comment: ну и выбросьте из кода все начиная с @time - ниже это пример использования, он не нужен

Comment: спасибо ,сработало